Why isn't Rust narrowing my types inside my match statement?
I have a codebase with the same logic (to get a Vector of bytes) copy-pasted repeatedly:
pub fn main() {
    let name = String::from("steve");
    let age: u64 = 20;
    let bytes: Vec<u8> = [name.as_bytes().to_vec(), age.to_le_bytes().to_vec()].concat();
    print!("{:#?}", bytes);
}

To ensure the logic is consistent, I would like to create a function to generate the bytes based on the inputs, using the appropriate method from the input's type:
enum SeedInput {
    U64,
    String,
}

impl SeedInput {
    pub fn to_bytes(&self) -> &[u8] {
        match self {
            SeedInput::U64 => self.to_le_bytes(),
            SeedInput::String => self.as_bytes(),
        }
    }
}

pub fn create_seeds_from_inputs(inputs: Vec<&SeedInput>) -> Vec<&[u8]> {
    let mut seeds: Vec<&[u8]> = Vec::new();
    for input in inputs {
        seeds.push(input.to_bytes());
    }
    seeds
}

I understand the errors I am receiving: no method named 'to_le_bytes' found for reference `&SeedInput` in the current scope, but my understanding is that inside this part of the match statement we should have already narrowed the type of SeedInput to be U64.
Why isn't Rust narrowing the type? How can I run a method that is specific to the matched type?

Your enum variants do not carry any data.

@justinas But a U64 and a String etc do carry data. Could you please rephrase? If you mean that I'm not calling create_seeds_from_inputs() yet - yes, I'm trying to get it to compile first.

Only because you name enum types like Rust types doesn't mean Rust knows what you intend to do...

@8192K The enum types are Rust types. Rust Analyzer wants eg U64 rather than u64. If I use a lower cased type, the error given will be: rustc(non_camel_case_types)

U64 is the the name of the enum variant. In this case, each variant is a unit variant - they carry no data, akin to C enums. You probably mean U64(u64) and String(String)

Thanks @PitaJ. Looks like Rust analyzer led me astray there. I've updated the code accordingly. I still get a fature on string.as_bytes().

Downvoter: how can I improve the question?

hint: you're using match wrong. In your updated code, u64 and string are both catch-all patterns. They don't refer to the type being matched.

@PitaJ Thanks again. I found the saem thing, I just updated match and it's now compiling, see update 2 above. I just need to fux the let bytes line so I don't have to re-specify the type of input.

Solving your final ask is more involved. Probably what you want is adding impl From<String> for Input etc and then creating a replacement vec! macro that calls Input::from on each element.

But a better solution for you would probably be to change Input to a trait to begin with, and create a custom vec!-like macro that just calls Input::to_bytes on each element.

OK thanks @PitaJ. I've updated it so the program now compiles and works. Do you want to add an answer?

@PitaJ thanks again. I've added an answer based on your help here but feel free to add your own and I'll accept it.

@PitaJ Also done: re vec_inputs!

Your code did not work for three reasons.

SeedInput::U64 and SeedInput::String do not represent actual Rust types, they are variants of an enum.

Your SeedInput enum does not carry any data, as pointed out by justinas. When you call self.to_le_bytes() inside your match expression, you are calling it on SeedInput, which is zero-sized. What you should be doing is calling it on an instance of u64.

There are ownership issues with your code also. You aim to return &[u8], which would work well with the String variant, but cannot work with the u64 variant. This is because u64::to_le_bytes() returns a [u8; 8], which is then owned by the current function, SeedInput::to_bytes(). It is therefore a temporary value, and you cannot return a reference to it.


The only way to make this work is by returning a Vec<u8> from SeedInput::to_bytes().
Why?
Because

you cannot return a reference, because that is not possible with u64.
you cannot return an owned [u8; {const}], because String is dynamically sized, you cannot know how big of an array you will need.

enum SeedInput {
    U64(u64),
    String(String)
}

impl SeedInput {
    pub fn to_bytes(&self) -> Vec<u8> {
        match self {
            Self::U64(num) => num.to_le_bytes().to_vec(),
            Self::String(s) => s.as_bytes().to_vec()
        }
    }
}


As people pointed out in the comments, the Rust Analyzer message re:
enum SeedInput {
    u64,
    string,
}


convert the identifier to upper camel case: U64rustc(non_camel_case_types)

Which asked me to convert them to TitleCase was misleading. I modified the code to use TitleCase:
enum SeedInput {
    U64,
    String,
}

Which is not what I was seeking to do. The correct syntax for an Enum here is actually:
enum Input {
    U64Input(u64),
    StringInput(String),
}


I did look in the Rust Book for this but couldn't couldn't find anything.
The following code then works:
trait Input {
    fn to_bytes(&self) -> Vec<u8>;
}

impl Input for u64 {
    fn to_bytes(&self) -> Vec<u8> {
        self.to_le_bytes().to_vec()
    }
}

impl Input for String {
    fn to_bytes(&self) -> Vec<u8> {
        self.as_bytes().to_vec()
    }
}

fn inputs_to_bytes(inputs: Vec<Box<dyn Input>>) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut bytes: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    for input in inputs {
        bytes.extend(input.to_bytes());
    }
    bytes
}

macro_rules! vec_inputs {
    ( $( $x:expr ),* ) => {
        {
            let mut temp_vec: Vec<Box<dyn Input>> = Vec::new();
            $(
                temp_vec.push(Box::new($x));
            )*
            temp_vec
        }
    };
}

pub fn main() {
    let name = String::from("steve");
    let age: u64 = 20;
    let bytes = inputs_to_bytes(vec_inputs![name, age]);
    print!("{:#?}", bytes);
}


If you want to see a good code example of how to use enums in a more complex case, I can recommend reading the source code of serde_json::Value. In my opinion that one is very clean. Not sure how well it fits your usecase, I just wanted to leave it here. Maybe it helps.
